# Access json object in php

Tags: php, json

I have a following code:

```
$string = '{"tracking_url":{"11":{"affiliate":"OMG","url_part1":<<some url>>,"url_part2":<<some url>>"}}}';
$points = json_decode( $string, true );
```

How do I access `url_part1` and `url_part2`?

Comment: Should have {} around all of that, no?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php has a pretty straight forward example (#2).

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($json))` will show you what needs to be done.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Actually i presented just a part of JSON so missed the 1st curly. I ab able to decode without any error but dont know how to echo it

Answer (score 5):

Your given string is not valid JSON.

I assume you have something like this

```
{ "tracking_url":{"11":{"affiliate":"OMG","url_part1":<<some url>>,"url_part2":<<some url>>"}} }
```

Then you can access the properties after parsing by

```
$obj = json_decode( '{ "tracking_url":{"11":{"affiliate":"OMG","url_part1":<<some url>>,"url_part2":<<some url>>"}} }', true );
```

I forgot the output part. As is set the second argument of `json_decode()` to true, the result is an associative array and you can access/output it like this:

```
echo $obj['tracking_url']['11']['url_part1'];
echo $obj['tracking_url']['11']['url_part2'];
```

Comment: `$obj->{'url_part1'}` and `$obj->{'url_part2'}` are then your variables.

Comment: @Sirko sorry for the unstructured question. I am able to decode it but dont know how to echo url_part1 and url_part2

Comment: @bozdoz  How would i echo them??

Comment: Write echo in front. @user2129794

Comment: @bozdoz dude `echo $obj->{'url_part1'}` is giving an error and is not the right way to access it.

Comment: Sorry, missed some of the path to the object value: should be: `echo $points->{'tracking_url'}->{'11'}->{'url_part1'};`