# Parsing JSON - getting null output - PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

My code:

```
$json_response = json_decode($response, true);
$tag= $json_response['results']['tags'][0]['tag'];
print $tag;
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "tagging_id": null,
      "image": "image.jpg",
      "tags": [
        {
          "confidence": 100,
          "tag": "herb"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 98.3637619018555,
          "tag": "plant"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to output "herb". I have looked up through examples but cannot figure out where the bug is.

I am reading results and then the trees.

Comment: Do a `print_r($json_response);` to see the nesting. `$tag = $json_response['results'][0]['tags'][0]['tag'];`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5b3ysyDu

Comment: https://3v4l.org/kki58

Comment: Position `results` is an array of objects; in this case there is only one object in the array.

Comment: Heh... this issue is the exact opposite of a prior issue you had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488760/json-parsing-outputs-null-php Thats kinda funny ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fetch the first element inside `['results']`.

```
echo $json_response['results'][0]['tags'][0]['tag'];
```